# Refund payment process error

Tags: visas

I cancelled my visa appointment because I made a mistake in my application and after speaking with UK visa and immigration I was suggested to cancel my appointment and I opted to ask for a refund. When I went to refund request and typed my reason, it allowed me to process further. It took me to a grey cell, which is the payment date, showing the current date, and didn't allow me to edit it. Can someone please tell me what I should do? I have already cancelled my appointment.

Comment: Perhaps a screenshot would help in better explaining the grey cell